# Copy only files that are unaffected by bad sectors

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks

How to copy every file that not affected by bad sector? I've tried `rsync`:

```
rsync --ignore-errors -a --progress --remove-source-files /media/x/S4T32kbad/ /media/x/w8tnew/
```

... but it too slow. I've also tried:

```
echo 5 > /sys/block/sdc/device/timeout
```

then

```
sudo fsck -ycfv /dev/sdc1
```

But it shows:

```
Error writing file system info: Input/output error
```

How to make copy process of files that not in bad sector faster?

I'm using external 4TB seagate hard disk via USB3 (which is 2nd 4TB seagate broken this year).

Comment: First thing I'd do is figure out *what kind of error(s)* you get (so please edit question with more information, e.g. `dmesg`, `smartctl`) - if you have so many bad blocks that you estimate 24 days for completion, than either the harddisk is damaged beyond rescue, or you have a transport layer problem. And if it's a transport layer problem, taking the disk out of the USB enclosure and connecting it directly to SATA to avoid the USB-to-SATA bridge may (or may not) help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ***ddrescue*** ? It might be useful. Details can be found in this document on [GNU ddrescue Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples).

Comment: yes, but the speed for phase 1 seems as fast as rsync (24days), so now i'm using rsync instead..

Comment: You could try create an image and restore that image in a good disk, then copy the files.